# Adding a new story board to my Project

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, interface-builder

I have added a new storyboard in my project but i am unable to view the Designer part of the story board. It is only showing me the backend XML data. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on storyboard file:[image]